# How to install dpkg-reconfigure?

Tags: installation, dpkg, amazon-ec2

I want to install `dpkg-reconfigure` in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS install on Amazon EC2? How to go about it?

Comment: I needed to know that `dpkg-reconfigure` needs to be ran as root otherwise the command is not found

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dpkg-reconfigure` is provided by the **`debconf`** package, which *should* always be installed in any Ubuntu 12.04 install. If it's not, use:

```
sudo apt-get install debconf
```

---

In your case, you are running Amazon's AMI Linux which is based on CentOS, not Ubuntu. That's why `apt-get` or `dpkg-reconfgure`, which are native to Debian/Ubuntu, are not available on your EC2 instance.

Comment: It is not installed and when I run your suggested I am getting the response `sudo: apt-get: command not found`

Comment: If `apt-get` is not available on an *Ubuntu* EC2 instance, you should open a ticket with Amazon Support...

Comment: I have asked a related question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/175325/is-my-amazon-ec-2-running-amazon-linux-or-ubuntu

Comment: Answered that and edited this one. You need to install an official Ubuntu AMI; Amazons is based on CentOS which is quite different as you're finding out.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it's already installed in Ubuntu. But if you are using some customized version without dpkg, you should be able to install using the command

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg
```

Comment: You cannot do that; `dpkg` is needed for `apt-get` to work.

Answer (score 1):

If `debconf` is installed, it's located in `/usr/sbin` what might not be in your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh Kubuntu 12.10 install, you will need to install these additional packages:

- ia32libs (¼ GiB!)
- libc6-i386
- lib32asound2
- lib32z1
- nspluginwrapper

If you forget one, and try to install the Receiver deb package, the package system will end up in sort of a limbo.  In that case (only!), run:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r icaclient
```

To remove the half-installed Receiver and start over.

After installing the 64-but Citrix Receiver 12.1 (or any NPAPI plugin for that matter), you need to reconfigure nspluginwrapper:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure nspluginwrapper
```

This triggers the nspluginwrapper installer to look for new NPAPI plugins and link them into the various installed browsers in the correct manner.

Comment: Oops, this is actually an answer for this Q: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204312/citrix-receiver-on-ubuntu-12-10 ... I am unable to post it over there, because it requires site karma (reputation points) that I do not have.  Could someone move the above answer to the correct question, so that Kubuntu users may also have their cup of Citrix Receiver?